# Insertar datos de una lista múltiple con PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Quiero hacer un INSERT a la base de datos con los datos que recojo de una lista múltiple. El caso es que algo estoy haciendo mal porque mi código no me funciona

Mi pagina es esta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi codigo es este

```
<?php

require 'conexionBD.php';

#EQUIPOS DE LA BASE DE DATOS
$sql="SELECT * FROM equipos LEFT JOIN registro_actual ON equipos.ID=registro_actual.ID_equipo WHERE registro_actual.ID IS NULL AND equipos.hostname != 'W7-ADMINISTRADOR'>
$cursor=$con->query($sql);
$equipos=[];
while($equipo=$cursor->fetch_object())
    $equipos[]=$equipo;

#FECHA ACTUAL
$sql="SELECT CONCAT (DAYNAME(CURDATE()),', ',DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE()),' de ',MONTHNAME(CURDATE()),' del ',YEAR(CURDATE()),' a las ',CURRENT_TIME) AS 'fecha'";
$cursor=$con->query($sql);
$fecha=$cursor->fetch_object();

if (isset ($_POST['conexiones'],$_POST['fechafin'])):
    $conexiones=$_POST['conexiones'];
    $fechafin=$_POST['fechafin'];
    foreach ($conexiones as $conexion) {
        $sql="INSERT INTO registro_actual (ID_equipo, fecha_fin) VALUES ($conexion,'$fechafin')";
        $con->query($sql);
        header ('Location:/pagina.php');
    }
endif;
?>

<html>
<h1>Permitir Internet a los equipos</h1>
<?php if (empty($equipos)){ ?>
    <p style="color:red">Todos los equipos tienen salida a Internet</p>
<?php } else { ?>
    <form method="POST">
    Seleccione los equipos a los que quiera permitir Internet:<br>
        <select name="conexiones[]" multiple>
            <?php foreach ($equipos as $equipo): ?>
                <option value=<?=$equipo->ID?>><?=$equipo->hostname?></option>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </select><br>
        Fecha de inicio: <b><?=$fecha->fecha?></b><br>
        Fecha de fin -> formato (año-mes-dia hora:minuto:segundo): <br><input type="text" name="fechafin" placeholder="Fecha Fin"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Permitir">
    </form>
<?php } ?>
```

Mis tablas:

```
mysql> DESCRIBE equipos;

+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |

+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

| ID       | int         | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |

| hostname | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |

| ip       | varchar(15) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |

+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

3 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> DESCRIBE registro_actual;

+--------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+

| Field        | Type      | Null | Key | Default           | Extra             |

+--------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+

| ID           | int       | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment    |

| ID_equipo    | int       | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                   |

| fecha_inicio | timestamp | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | DEFAULT_GENERATED |

| fecha_fin    | timestamp | YES  |     | NULL              |                   |

+--------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+

4 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

Mi codigo es este (lo pongo aqui porque si no me dice que tengo mucho codigo)

```
<?php

require 'conexionBD.php';



#EQUIPOS DE LA BASE DE DATOS

$sql="SELECT * FROM equipos LEFT JOIN registro_actual ON equipos.ID=registro_actual.ID_equipo WHERE registro_actual.ID IS NULL AND equipos.hostname != 'W7-ADMINISTRADOR'>

$cursor=$con->query($sql);

$equipos=[];

while($equipo=$cursor->fetch_object())

    $equipos[]=$equipo;



#FECHA ACTUAL

$sql="SELECT CONCAT (DAYNAME(CURDATE()),', ',DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE()),' de ',MONTHNAME(CURDATE()),' del ',YEAR(CURDATE()),' a las ',CURRENT_TIME) AS 'fecha'";

$cursor=$con->query($sql);

$fecha=$cursor->fetch_object();

if (isset ($_POST['conexiones'],$_POST['fechafin'])):

    $conexiones=$_POST['conexiones'];

    $fechafin=$_POST['fechafin'];

    foreach ($conexiones as $conexion) {

    $sql="INSERT INTO registro_actual (ID_equipo, fecha_fin) VALUES ($conexion,'$fechafin')";

    $con->query($sql);

    header ('Location:/pagina.php');

}

endif;

?>



<html>

<h1>Permitir Internet a los equipos</h1>

<?php if (empty($equipos)){ ?>

    <p style="color:red">Todos los equipos tienen salida a Internet</p>

<?php } else { ?>

    <form method="POST">

    Seleccione los equipos a los que quiera permitir Internet:<br>

        <select name="conexiones[]" multiple>

            <?php foreach ($equipos as $equipo): ?>

                <option value=<?=$equipo->ID?>><?=$equipo->hostname?></option>

            <?php endforeach ?>

        </select><br>

        Fecha de inicio: <b><?=$fecha->fecha?></b><br>

        Fecha de fin -> formato (año-mes-dia hora:minuto:segundo): <br><input type="text" name="fechafin" placeholder="Fecha Fin"><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Permitir">

    </form>

<?php } ?>
```

Mis tablas:

```
mysql> DESCRIBE equipos;

+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |

+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

| ID       | int         | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |

| hostname | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |

| ip       | varchar(15) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |

+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

3 rows in set (0,00 sec)



mysql> DESCRIBE registro_actual;

+--------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+

| Field        | Type      | Null | Key | Default           | Extra             |

+--------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+

| ID           | int       | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment    |

| ID_equipo    | int       | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                   |

| fecha_inicio | timestamp | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | DEFAULT_GENERATED |

| fecha_fin    | timestamp | YES  |     | NULL              |                   |

+--------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+

4 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

Comment: esto debes incluirlo en tu post, dándole en edit... en la parte de abajo debe ir las respuestas y estas no es una respuesta por favor corrígelo.

Comment: No me deja. Si lo hago así pone que tengo mucho codigo y no me deja publicarlo

Comment: ¿Que error te muestra? Facilita toda la info del error para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: No da ningún error. Simplemente cuando en el formulario haces click en permitir, directamente no inserta